# I want to remove pandas cell content if it is only consists of stop words with python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, nltk

I have this code to remove ant stop words from pandas data frame:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my-file.csv', sep=',', engine='python')


df["English term"] = df["English term"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([word for word in x.split() if word not in stop_words]))
```

I don't want to remove all the stop words inside the content. I want to remove the cell content if it only consists of stop words.

By the way, I have little experience in python for this question that it may seem so simple.

Comment: Please provide an example of your DataFrame

Comment: my data frame is just a simple 2 excel sheet columns converted to CSV. nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
df = df[~df["English term"].isin(stop_words)]
```

Comment: I get this error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it